# ASP.NET Validation of viewstate MAC failed - IIS recycled

Tags: .net, iis

I've seen this issue in many posts. In my asp.net site I keep track of any error that occurs using a log that is populated using Application_Error method in Global.asax file.

ASP.NET Validation of viewstate MAC failed is an error that occurs quite often. My guess, is that this happens after IIS recycles my app.

I've seen many posts saying that adding a machine static key in the web.config would solve this.

My question is: **what does adding a machine static key do exactly?**

Answer (score 3):

The Machine Static Key is a fix only for the [Web Farm](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Web+farm) scenario.  The key on the browser must match the key on the server to avoid this error.

When a customer visits a site on a web farm, they may start on server A and have that key stored client-side, but on the postback be hitting server B.  In this case, server B would balk, unless both server A and server B are configured with the same key.

In your case, with the app pool recycling, this isn't a potential fix.

Like you, our team has a central error logging system, and we use a global error handler in the global.asax. W e have a web interface that we can use to review the errors.

We have a similar issue - we get these errors, too, and others that aren't really worth noting, but they get logged anyway.

We simply log our errors differently for certain known errors that we wish to ignore.  (Sporadic timeout issues that don't cause a total failure, etc.)  We have a Severity Level in our global error logging system, and these get logged as SeverityLevel.KnownIssue or SeverityLevel.Informational.  Our web interface simply filters these out so we don't see them on our main review screens, but if we need to dig in and get statistics on these, we have the data handy.

Comment: I wasn't aware adding a machine static key would only fix this issue in a web farm scenario. This is not my case. Is there a way to fix this error in a non web farm scenario (without disabling ViewstateMac)? Thanks